# OOP (Philosophical)

Tags: oop, architecture, domain-driven-design

When developing domain models, I can see two major ways of thinking about the design of the classes/entities. The first one assumes that a program as a kind of "simulation" of what happens in the real world. With that approach you would have a Customer class -for example- with perhaps methods that correspond to the actions a Customer can perform. Whenever the customer wants to do something, the corresponding method is called. The other approach would be to design the classes as if they were exposed to the user and s/he then has the ability to create and play with the objects “directly”, thinking of the program as a kind of extension of the user’s reality. With this approach, a Customer class would probably make no sense as the customer is already “involved”. I've read some articles talking about adding security at the method level, which seems to be consistent with this approach, but I believe both are used in the wild. How do you deal with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, book/article recommendation questions are not welcome on Stack Overflow. Please read the [help/on-topic] about what kinds of questions are acceptable.

Comment: No problem, I changed the question to comply.

Answer (score 1):

When developing a domain model you should **never** simulate what happens in the real world.

The **real** world is too complex and you need a domain model to simplify your specific application development. I've seen a few domain models defined as either "very flexible" (that is very abstract) or "realistic" (that means too detailed and complex to be understood), and all lead to project failures.

A domain model should contain only the domain expert's knowledge relevant to the application (that is **always** a small fraction of his knowledge) expressed in code that use his own language. And it should split in bounded contexts that further reduce the cognitive load.

If **he** talks about "trains", you can have a `Train` class in your domain model; if he talks about strategies, you can have a `Strategy` class in your domain model, but you can't have a Strategy class in the domain just because you find that something that he calls "player" can be implemented with a [strategy pattern](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

What you **could** have to simulate is the "paper process" that the expert actually use to provide a real world service.

For the rest of the question, it's something to evaluate case by case, application by application.

For example in the financial applications that I develop, different roles can sometimes use the same concepts in different ways. When I'm sure that the concept is **exactly** the same, I use [bounded roles](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/bounded_roles.html) to express the differences. But note that this never happen to entity, just to value objects and domain services. If you find two roles talking about an identificable object (aka an entity), you know that the only thing that the two roles shares is the identity of the object, but they are thinking of different things.

Bounded roles are similar to what you say about your ipothetical Customer class.

Comment: I understand that models are simplifications and that a given entity can have multiple roles. My question is related to how the user (the actual person) is supposed to "participate" or interact with the models, because that would -or might- have an impact in the design. Is the user "involved", or some kind of spectator? In other words, do you assume the code in your domain model executes in the context of a user, or not? And why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you question it is mainly about viewpoint. The answer is: the PoV and respective terms you should be using are totally *application-specific*.

As an example consider what happens when you buy something at your local grocery store. From the store PoV they're *selling* goods to you. From your PoV, as a customer, you're *purchasing* goods. If you're implementing application for the point-of-sale terminal, you will model concepts like Customer, Sale, Product, Discount etc. On the opposite, if you're developing simple iOS application to track expenses, you'll be modeling concepts like Income, Expense (which could be that purchase), Place (which could be that grocery store) and so on. There is no point to model such concept as Customer in the context of this app, simply because there is always only one Customer - a current user, you. But modeling such concept as a Customer is perfectly ok within a context of PoS terminal application, which might need that to apply discounts or send marketing promotions.

The model, its granularity and respective terms will match a point of view and needs of the application being developed.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. But how does it affect domain models? Does it imply that domain models are application (or point-of-view) specific? And even if we "lock" the point of view, is your comment indirectly suggesting that the second approach is preferred?

Comment: >> Does it imply that domain models are application (or point-of-view) specific?
Absolutely. It's context dependent.